# Error Copying data from HDFS to External Table In Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

i am trying to insert data from hdfs to external table in hive. but getting below error.

Error :

```
Usage: java FsShell [-put <localsrc> ... <dst>]
Command failed with exit code = 255
```

Command

```
hive> !hadoop fs -put /myfolder/logs/pv_ext/2013/08/11/log/data/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv
    > ;
```

Edited:

```
file location : /yapstone/logs/pv_ext/somedatafor_7_11/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv

table location : hdfs://sandbox:8020/yapstone/logs/pv_ext/2013/08/11/log/data
```

i am in hive
executing command

```
!hadoop fs -put /yapstone/logs/pv_ext/somedatafor_7_11/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv hdfs://sandbox:8020/yapstone/logs/pv_ext/2013/08/11/log/data
```

getting error :

```
put: File /yapstone/logs/pv_ext/somedatafor_7_11/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv does not exist.
Command failed with exit code = 255
```

Please share your suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods to load data into the external `Hive` table.

**Method 1:**

a) Get the location of the `HDFS` folder for the `Hive` external table.

```
hive> desc formatted mytable;
```

b) Note the value for the `Location` property in output. Say, it is `hdfs:///hive-data/mydata`

c) Then, put the file from local disk to `HDFS`

```
$ hadoop fs -put /location/of/data/file.csv hdfs:///hive-data/mydata
```

**Method 2:**

a) Load data via this `Hive` command

```
hive > LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/location/of/data/file.csv' INTO TABLE mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks but when i tried 1st statement getting error like : ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'hadoop' 'fs' '-'

Comment: when i tried 2nd option getting error like : ParseException line 1:23 mismatched input '/' expecting StringLiteral near 'INPATH' in load statement

Comment: The `hadoop fs -put` statement should be executed on the command line (not hive shell prompt)

Comment: For the error using Method 2, I think it may be due to the quotes. Ensure that the quotes are single-quotes `'` and not backticks.

Comment: i have edited the question, may someone please help me what error i am doing here

Comment: Can you try executing `hadoop fs -put` command from command line?

Comment: i did like this. hive> !hadoop fs -put /yapstone/logs/pv_ext/somedatafor_7_11/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv hdfs://sandbox:8020/yapstone/logs/pv_ext/2013/08/11/log/data

Comment: but same error : /yapstone/logs/pv_ext/somedatafor_7_11/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv does not exist.

Comment: What does this command output? `ls -l /yapstone/logs/pv_ext/somedatafor_7_11/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv`

Comment: ya yapstone is appearing when execute ls -l

Comment: Then, it might be a file permissions issue. You can try using `chown` and/or `chmod` to change the file ownership and/or permissions so that Hadoop can access it.

Answer (score 0):

One more method. Change Hive table location:

```
alter table table_name set location='hdfs://your_data/folder';
```

Answer (score 0):

This method may help you to better.

1. Need to create a table in HIVE.

   `hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(myid INT, a1 STRING, a2 STRING....) 
   row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile LOCATION 
   hdfs://sandbox:8020/yapstone/logs/pv_ext/2013/08/11/log/data;`
2. Load data from HDFS to hive table.

   `hive> LOAD DATA INPATH /yapstone/logs/pv_ext/somedatafor_7_11/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv INTO TABLE mytable;`

   NOTE: If you load data from HDFS to HIVE (INPATH) the data will be moved from HDFS 
   location  to HIVE. So, the data won't available on HDFS location for next time.
3. Check if the data loaded successfully.

   `hive> SELECT * FROM mytable;`